# PySpark - SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext File does not exist

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have small piece code in PySpark, but I keep getting errors. I'm new to this so im not sure where to start.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Open json").setMaster("local[3]")

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
print("Done")
```

I ran this in cmd with the command :

```
spark-submit .\PySpark\Open.py
```

I then get the following error statement:

> C:\Users\Abdullah\Documents\Master Thesis>spark-submit
>   .\PySpark\Open.py

```
 18/06/30 15:21:58 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-Java classes where applicable 
18/06/30 15:22:01 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext. java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/C:/Users/Abdullah/Documents/Master%20Thesis/PySpark/Open.py does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1529)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1499)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:461)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Abdullah/Documents/Master Thesis/./PySpark/Open.py", line 12, i n <module>
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)   File "C:\apache-spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark
\context.py", line 118, in __init__   File
"C:\apache-spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark
\context.py", line 180, in _do_init   File
"C:\apache-spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark
\context.py", line 282, in _initialize_context   File
"C:\apache-spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip
\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1525, in __call__   File
"C:\apache-spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip
\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
None.org.apache.spa rk.api.java.JavaSparkContext. :
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
file:/C:/Users/Abdullah/Documents/Master%2 0Thesis/PySpark/Open.py
does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLo
calFileSystem.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1529)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1499)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:461)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `PySpark/Open.py does not exist`...

Comment: Can you show the output of running just pyspark command?

Comment: The last part in the yellow box is the output of the pyspark command.

Comment: Trying to reformat your output... Anyways, all that says is it cannot find your file. Please show in your question the full path to it

Comment: Also, try removing the space in `Master Thesis` directory and run it again

Comment: OMG!! Thats it! It totally fixed it. THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!!! I was working on this for two days. One. Stupid. Space. I can't belief this.

Comment: Welcome. I almost always use underscores and dashes after running into errors like this

Answer (score -1):

As per your logs you are trying to run Apache Spark on window machine.

You need to add win util and add path in env variable

- Download the executable [winutils](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/hdp-win-alpha/winutils.exe) from the Hortonworks repository, or from Amazon AWS platform  or github [winutils](http://sundog-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/winutils.exe).
- Create a directory where you place the executable winutils.exe. For example, C:\SparkDev\x64. Add the environment variable %HADOOP_HOME% which points to this directory, then add %HADOOP_HOME%\bin to PATH.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I already said the enviroment variables up in the way you described. I also put the winutils file in the right directory, but I keep getting the same error. Should I maybe delete everything and install spark and hadoop from scratch?

Comment: Check your path,go to cmd and type "path" , is winutil showing on path?  , this is common error for windows user

Comment: I have the directory C:\hadoop\bin and inside the bin folder I have the winutils.exe  file. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes ,path is correct check env variable hadoop home and path,also check winutil not corrupted

Comment: Nevermind. I had a space in the name of my directory that totally messed thing up. Thanks anyways!